# Align text left and right in the same list element

Tags: html, css

I want to have a list element with a text aligned to the left, and another text aligned to the right.

I have tried this: https://jsfiddle.net/dso5x75g, but it doesn't work as I expect, because the "dot" is over the text.

How can I do it properly?

My code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div style="float:left;">Pizza </div>
        <div style="float:right;">€ 20,00</div>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 10):

You forgot to clear the default `ul` styles. Add following css:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

As you are using `float` so set the layout of `li` as well:

```
ul li {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or use `:after` pseudo element:

```
ul li:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div style="float:left;">Pizza </div>
    <div style="float:right;">€ 20,00</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Instead of using floats, you can also use css3 [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to align text in both directions. You will need following css:

```
ul li {
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: flex;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul li {
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>Pizza </div>
    <div>€ 20,00</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If the goal is to use custom image as bullets, you can draw them with `:before` pseudo element:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
ul li {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

ul li:before {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  content: '';
  width: 5px;
  left: 0;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div style="float:left;">Pizza </div>
    <div style="float:right;">€ 20,00</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the above snippet, you can change `background-color` with `background-image` and set `width` and `height` accordingly. This will give you absolute control over the position of image and indents between image and text.

Comment: But I want to show an images on each element using `list-style-image`..

Comment: @MattiaF. Just on left side or on both sides?

Comment: @MattiaF. Check this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dso5x75g/2/). You can replace `background-color` with `background-image`.